# Join two lists using linq queries - C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, join, linq-query-syntax

I have an assignment where I have to join two lists of the same type (Customer). They have similar entries which I have to avoid repetitions.

This is my **customer** class:

```
class Customer
{
  private String _fName, _lName;
  private int _age, _cusIndex;
  private float _expenses;

  public Customer(String fName, String lName, int age, float expenses, int cusIndex)
  {
    this._fName = fName;
    this._lName = lName;
    this._age = age;
    this._expenses = expenses;
    this._cusIndex = cusIndex;
  }
}
```

So I have two `List<Customer>`s named `customers1` and `customers2`. I need to join these two without using Collections methods (like `customer1.Union(customer2).ToList();` But using Linq queries.

Here's the **Linq query** I wrote:

```
var joined = (from c1 in customers1
              join c2 in customers2
              on c1.CusIndex equals c2.CusIndex
              select new {c1, c2});
```

But this gives me the member who appear on both of the lists. But I need all, without repetition. Are there any solution ???

Comment: 1. Override [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173147.aspx) and [GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) in your `Customer` class (to reflect that two customers are considered equal, if their `CusIndex` is equal). 2. `var joined = customers1.Concat(customers2).Distinct();`

Comment: It looks like there is no query equivalent for `Union` method. What is the reason of not using `Union` method?

Comment: @Corak Yes. I've already done that. But the problem is, this query returns the Customers who are in both of the lists. But I need everyone

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev As I mentioned, this is an assignment :/

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge - [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302894.aspx) basically just enumerates *the whole* first enumerable *and then the whole* second enumerable. [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436.aspx) then basically skips all elements that have already been yielded. That's giving you, what you want: *everyone* (from both lists), but only *once*. But since [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341731.aspx) seems to work for you (I guess it does the same under the hood), use that. :)

Comment: Yes, according to [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) it does. Relevant implementation (look for `UnionIterator`): `Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer); foreach (TSource element in first) if (set.Add(element)) yield return element; foreach (TSource element in second) if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;`

Comment: Thanks @Corak buddy !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like there is no query equivalent for `Union` method. You will need to use this method either in method chain call or in your query.

If you look at [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.110).aspx) on returning the set union of two sequences, you will see the following official query:

```
var infoQuery =
    (from cust in db.Customers
    select cust.Country)
    .Union
        (from emp in db.Employees
        select emp.Country)
;
```

So, there are only two options in your case:

1. Method chain:

   ```
   var joined = customers1.Union(customers2);
   ```
2. LINQ query

   ```
   var joined = (from c1 in customers1
                 select c1)
                .Union
                    (from c2 in customers2
                     select c2);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Distinct to filter out the duplicates?

```
 var joined =  (from c1 in customers1
          join c2 in customers2
          on c1.CusIndex equals c2.CusIndex
          select new {c1, c2}).Distinct();
```

There is a nice [extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxMin/) in `Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities`. It has a function called `DistinctBy`, which may be more relevant in your case.

Comment: I used this. But when I tried to convert it into a new List using `ToList()` method, It gives me Error. `cannot implicitly convert type`

Comment: This is similar to a [self join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm). ToList() will give you an anonymous collection. I am confused about what you are trying to achieve. You cannot cast an anonymous type to a known type.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to join two Lists without repetitive elements. It's a part of an assignment !

Comment: Then you have to `Union` to combine two collections and then `Distinct` to filter out duplicates. Or you can use `Intersect`, then `Union` and then `Except`. There are many ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried and succeed the method provided by @yeldarKurmangaliyev